# Uploading local website code to WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So I got a client that wants me to work on his WordPress website. The issue is, the code he shared with were just PHP files and a database dumb. However, on WordPress, I see importing only takes projects exported from WordPress as XML files. Is there another way I can set this up from local PHP files, JS, and CSS scripts back to WordPress?

Here is the file structure:
[image: Unzipped files]

Comment: Sure, you import the database dump into your database, for example using phpMyAdmin, or the mysql command line tool.

Comment: I want the project setup in my WordPress not locally. It's a WordPress website.

Comment: "In my WordPress" meaning what exactly, on wordpress.com? _Why not_ locally?

Comment: Ok, let's assume it's a local WordPress installation. How do I import this project? Remember it's zipped not exported.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip up all the files, transfer them to the webhosting webserver main webserver directory, sometimes under a folder named public_html  using SFTP client. Then unzip it,then the index.php should be accessible. Be sure to upload the .sql file (mysql database data) into your mysql database that should be created on the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Already imported the database, just wondering how I can copy the files to WordPress. I can't find a public_html folder after installing WordPress on my PC. I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: To transfer the files to the server, you need SFTP server like openssh installed on ubuntu. Then you need a SFTP client on Windows or wherever your wordpress files are to transfer them. A SFTP client like Filezilla is a solid choice and it will connect with your openssh installed on ubuntu to move those files over.